# C# async socket reading and writing at the same time?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I am writing a tcp chat server at the moment and i read a lot of articles about synchronous and asynchronous sockets.

I decided to use the async sockets because this way i don't have to manage the threads myself.(Anything reason i should to change my opinion ?)

In all the articles, it was nicely explained how to establish a connection and how to send and receive data BUT never what happens if there might be more than one message to send without a reply.

My Question is do i have to call `socket.endreceiving()` before i want to send something ??? If i don't what would happen if i receive a message at the same time i want to send one ??? (there are multiple threads but its still one underlying socket right?)

Comment: Can we have a code example please?

Comment: I dont really have code yet im still in the process of planning. Its a general question.

Comment: A feasibility study is an important part of technology selection. ie. Pick a technology and try it. If it fails and you don't know why, we would like to see that code.

Comment: No reason to change that opinion.  The sockets will be asynchronous no matter what you do; if you use the asynchronous API you won't be over-taxing the system with threads sitting around waiting for communications and thus be more scalable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find there an example of asynchronous TCP listener and client https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener

You can send and write and the same time, you cannot send from two threads at the same time through the same socket.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this is not a problem for `Socket.Send` or `Socket.SendAsync`

Comment: I have written modules that send data using TCP sockets across multiple threads. It is trivial with Socket.Send, and with SendAsync you just need to manage your buffers in a thread-safe manner.